# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'DataContracts.Market'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am getting the following error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Guid?' to 'DataContracts.Market'

---

```
    private CellSite MapEntityToCellSitePOCO(t_CellSite _cellsite)
    {

        CellSite cellsite= new CellSite();
        cellsite.SiteId = _cellsite.SiteID;
        cellsite.Market.MarketID = _cellsite.MarketId;
        cellsite.Region.RegionId = _cellsite.RegionId;


       return cellsite;
    }
```

the following is my datacontracts file

---

```
    public class CellSite
{


    public Guid CellSiteID { get; set; }

    public string SiteId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }
    public Market Market { get; set; }
    public Guid? ConstructionManager { get; set;}
   }
```

This is market.cs

```
      public class Market
{
    public Guid? MarketID { get; set; }
    public string OperatorMarketName { get; set; }
    public string MarketName { get; set; }
    public decimal AllOtherAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal RawLandAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal RenewalFee { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

there is a column MarketId in cellsite table which i want to bring on.how can i do that? I am new to entity frame work.
thanks in advance

Comment: Please share how you are mapping between the table and the POCOs you list here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your `Market` and `Region` properties first:

```
CellSite cellsite= new CellSite();
cellsite.SiteId = _cellsite.SiteID;

cellsite.Market = new Market();
cellsite.Market.MarketID = _cellsite.MarketId;

cellsite.Region = new Region();
cellsite.Region.RegionId = _cellsite.RegionId;
```